# Creating a Static bitmap from resource

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I've got the following problem

I want to create many instances of a view (dinamically). Each view can have one of 6 possible icons. What I wanted to do create a static Bitmap so that I can use in in the Draw function withouth having the same icon on memory 40 times....

like so:

```
public static final Bitmap InstinctBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tech), SmallIconSide, SmallIconSide, false);
```

Obviously this doesn't work because getResources() is not static. Any workaround? Or is this a bad Idea?

The onDraw method of the view keeps telling me that is a bad Idea to instatiate objects in it, so this is the choice I made

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i think its a bad idea .. please add some more information !!

Comment: There is really nothing more to add. I'll explain it again. I have Custom View. I need to generate several of these views (about 40) in the program. Each (depending on a configuration file) can have one of six possible icons. To draw that Icon in the OnDraw method I need to turn it into a Bitmap. If I manage to create a static Bitmap there will only be 6 loaded images in memory. Otherwise there will be 40. Is that better? (I've been told I m no clear when asking)

Comment: I agree with @r4jiv007, and would use an LruCache instead for this. However, the general approach to gaining static access to a Context (and thus getResources()) can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android